# SQL Use of Count and Sum

Tags: sql, count, sum, alias

I am trying to formulate an SQL query to both count and sum all of the order totals  in RETAIL_ORDER. Label the count of orders 'Total Number Orders' and the sum or orders 'Total Sales'

I have the following for a Query but the label for Total number orders is not going to the right place.

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderTotal), 
       SUM(OrderTotal) AS 'Total Sales',
       'Total Number Orders' 
FROM RETAIL_ORDER;
```

[MY Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loeEA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aliases of the columns must be written right after each column. 
The way you've written your query returns the column `COUNT(OrderTotal)` without an alias and a 3d column with the string `'Total Number Orders'` also without an alias.

Also don't use single quotes for the column names/aliases.
Depending on your database you can use double quotes or square brackets or backticks:

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderTotal) AS "Total Number Orders", 
       SUM(OrderTotal) AS "Total Sales" 
FROM RETAIL_ORDER;
```

Unless `OrderTotal` may contain `null`s `COUNT(OrderTotal)` could be written simpler as `COUNT(*)`.